# Unable to fetch details of B2B user using Azure Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

Azure's Graph API supports fetching details of a user using [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request). It supports either the id or the userPrincipalName(UPN). For B2B user the requirement is to fetch the details using UPN. The UPN that Azure creates for a B2B user is the following format 
 "B2BUserEmail#EXT#directoryid/Tenant"

When queried with above UPN format

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/b2buseremail.com#EXT#@<directory/tenant>`

the REST API fails and gives the following error

`{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource 'b2buseremail.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "d167220f-e0ef-4528-b7a5-de71fd524f07",
      "date": "2019-12-09T23:52:18"
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Currently Azure Graph API treats "#" as a special character and hence they have suggested to use "%23" instead of "#"

So the query would look like

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/b2buseremail.com%23EXT%23@<directory/tenant>`